# Moving tables data from sqlite3 to postgressql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

What is the simplest way to move data from sqlite3 tables to posgressql in Django project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform a data backup, we use the following command:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > data.json #use this command adding before postgres in django
```

This command will generate a data.json file in the root of your project, meaning you generated the dumpdata from SQLite and stored it in JSON format.

**Sync Database**

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb #Use this command only after creation of postgres in django.
```

**Load Data**

This command will change the database backend to PostgreSQL.

```
python manage.py loaddata data.json #This command dumps your previous data from SQlite into postgres.
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer. When I use python manage.py dumpdata > data.json it gives me the following  error  Cannot operate on a closed database.

Comment: (etisalatcash) C:\Users\Islam.Fayez\Desktop\Islam\KYCReview\KYCReview>python manage.py dumpdata > data.json
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-8: character maps to <undefined>
Exception ignored in: <generator object cursor_iter at 0x00000257D33CACF0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\IslamKYC\KYCReview\KYCReview\etisalatcash\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1876, in cursor_iter
    cursor.close()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.

Comment: please ensure  that you have sqlite3 database setting before running that comand

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

Comment: Do you have that sqlite3 database file in your project root?

Comment: Yes sure and the application is working normally

Comment: python3 manage.py dumpdata > data.json   try this way and see if it solves

Comment: Unfortunately not working he system cannot execute the specified program. thank you anyway I know you solution is working perfectly with the others I will check what's the problem

Comment: ok fine no problem